# Tornado web sockets and long-running Celery tasks

Tags: python, sockets, websocket, celery, tornado

I have a Tornado server that's used to submit long-running (~minutes) calculations by submitting tasks to some Celery workers with a RabbitMQ back-end. The tasks that are submitted are yielded in a Tornado coroutine inside a `WebSocketHandler`:

```
class MainWSHandler(WebSocketHandler):
    def open(self):
        logging.info("Connection opened.")

    def on_close(self):
        logging.info("Connection closed.")

    def on_message(self, message):
        result = self.submit_task(message)

        self.write_message("Calculation has been submitted")

    @gen.coroutine
    def submit_task(self, params):
        result = yield gen.Task(long_calculation.apply_async, args=[params])

        self.write_message("Completed calculation")

        return result
```

This works well if the user never leaves the page with the currently opened web socket. If they do, and the web socket closes, the returned message `self.write_message("Completed calculation")` will fail with a `WebSocketClosedError`. This is fine in cases where the user does not intend to come back to the page for awhile (that is, until after the calculation has been completed).

However, in the case where the user submits a calculation, leaves the page, and then returns before the calculation is finished, the same error is raised because the web socket has been closed and a new one opened. This prevents the calculation completion messages to propagate to the front-end.

My question is: is it possible to reconnect to the same web socket? Or, alternatively, how can I ensure that the message returned once the calculation has completed makes it to the user's current page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like I may have jumped the gun assuming that there's a structural solution to this problem inherent in this long-running-task-with-a-web-socket system.

It's enough to store the currently opened web socket in a class attribute

```
class MainWSHandler(WebSocketHandler):
    self.clients = {}

def open(self):
    logging.info("Connection opened.")
    self.clients[self.current_user] = self
```

And deal with the response from the task by using the stored web socket

```
@gen.coroutine
def submit_task(self, params):
    result = yield gen.Task(long_calculation.apply_async, args=[params])

    # Retrieve current web socket
    ws = self.clients[self.current_user]
    ws.write_message("Completed calculation")

    return result
```

There may be more efficient ways (or some idiomatic method), but I am satisfied with this solution for now.